# Triple Integrals: How to integrate it

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral, spherical-coordinates

Using spherical coordinates,

$$\iiint_D (x^2 + y^2 +z^2) dV, $$

where $D$ is the region above the cone  $z^2 = x^2+ y^2$ and below the plane $z=a$, $a>0$.

Over what region do we have to integrate this?

$\theta$ lies between $0$ and $2\pi$. But for $\rho$ it cannot be zero as well as $\phi$. I have tried to draw a diagram but I am not able to visualize the cone and the plane in the same place.

Can Someone please guide me on this problem?

Comment: Did you try drawing a diagram?

Comment: The upper limit for $\rho$ follows from $z=\rho\cos\phi=a \implies \rho=a\sec\phi$. You get the upper limit for $\phi$ from $z^2=x^2+y^2\implies\cos^2\phi=\sin^2\phi$, or $\tan\phi=1$ which means $\phi=\frac\pi4$ at most.

Comment: Like your last question, $z = a$ should give you upper bound of $\rho$. Use $z^2 = x^2 + y^2$ to find limits of $\phi$.

Comment: Can I ask you something? Each time, I worked question on triple integrals, I seem to miss an important step specially about phi and rho. Is there any way to remedy to this? I mean what are the steps you undertake to solve this question? I would be grateful to you if you could please help me out on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In spherical coordinates, the condition $z^2\geqslant x^2+y^2$ becomes $\rho^2\cos^2\phi\geqslant\rho^2\sin^2\phi$. Since $\rho\sin\phi=z\geqslant0$, $\phi\in\left[0,\frac\pi2\right]$, and then $\cos^2\phi\geqslant\sin^2\phi\iff\phi\in\left[0,\frac\pi4\right]$. The condition $z\leqslant a$ becomes $\rho\cos\phi\leqslant a$. So, compute$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^\frac a{\cos\phi}\rho^2\sin\phi\,\mathrm d\rho\,\mathrm d\phi\,\mathrm d\theta.$$